# How do I select text from image in Flutter app?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am making my first flutter app. What I am trying to achieve is to capture an image using imagepicker and then select text from it. I have tried implementing it using Firebase ML Vision, with the help of it's textRecognizer but that gives me the whole text in the image. Is there any way we can select text from the image, like using cursors to mark the beginning and end in image only?

Comment: You can do R&D on google lens app which is available on the play store(The app can able to do which you ask for).
nothing is impossible, you just have to do some research.
Pro Tip: Find on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not any widget available in flutter text select from image.

other wise you can uses tesseract_ocr packages.

example link : - https://morioh.com/p/a2d8611f086f